# How to convert image URL to bitmap in fastest way and save?

Tags: android, file, url, bitmapimage

Get `bitmap` from image `url` takes too much time when use -`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())`

Is there any better way to convert url to `bitmap` and save `image` in device? Because my app should work offline.
I have been using multiple methods for saving images like asynctask, picasso, etc. All these takes too much time. That is why i had to ask this question.

Comment: why you want to convert url to bitmap now a day lib available from loading image

Comment: You can use Picasso or Glide Image Libraries for that.

Comment: @Athira please check what is size of image by downloading via browser and check resolution. if its larger than required you can override image size via Glide or Picasso Libraries while download

Comment: I want to display image when device is offline

Comment: The only way you will be able to improve your code is if you use method profiling or other tools to determine exactly where your time is being spent. For example, if the time is being spent just in the downloading process, it is unlikely that this can be accelerated.

Comment: You can download images in background when user user is online which are compressed.then stored it in device display when app opens.for first time you need internet to download things and keep track of it. if its successfully stored in device.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code.It works...**
It will Downlaod image form url and save in SD card in mobile

```
try
 {   
      URL url =  new URL("Enter the URL to be downloaded");
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
  urlConnection.connect();                  
  File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
  String filename="downloadedFile.png";   
  Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
  if(file.createNewFile())
  {
    file.createNewFile();
  }                 
  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
  int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  int downloadedSize = 0;   
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bufferLength = 0;
  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
  {                 
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
  }             
  fileOutput.close();
  if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();    
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
  filepath=null;
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ;
return filepath;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It's easy to use to load `Bitmap` from `Url` and Cache them.

So, it saves your time.

Just you've to add this line.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(Uri).into(ImageView);
```

Comment: You can add your suggestions to comment.Please Dont add them as answer.

Comment: @Joker It could be an answer of his question.

Comment: If you want to add answer please upload code snippet for help or stackoverflow answer link it will be much helpful. Please take look at guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Joker Okay, thanks. But, may Picasso is the solution .

Comment: @Shakil  Yes Sure. Just Post Snippet.

Comment: @Joker So, should I add some code how to do that with Picasso? Or should I leave topics about Picasso?

Comment: @Shakil Just Post Sample Picasso Code How to get Bitmap using url if possible how to override size of image if large.you are good to go

Comment: Good To See Snippet.Well Done

Comment: @Joker Thanks. I'll keep this in mind for future answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(this)
                        .load(strUrl)
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                saveMyBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) resource).getBitmap());
                            }
                        });
```

Load bitmap from image url like this..

Comment: What is "saveMyBitmap" ? 
It gives me error can not resolve method 'into(anonymous com.bumptech.glide.request.target.SaimpleTarget<android.graphics.drawable..Drawable>'

Comment: it is function to save bitmap to file like...


try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}